# nmap ignoring --script parameter

Tags: ubuntu, redis, nmap

I have installed nmap 6.25 on an Ubuntu 12.04 server, and am trying to use the redis-info script. I have downloaded the script and put it in my home directory.  When I run:

```
nmap -p 6379 -Pn my.ip.num.ber --script redis-info.nse
```

it just does a normal scan, without even checking the script at all.

```
Host is up.
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
6379/tcp filtered unknown
```

That's it. It's a totally fresh install, I have changed nothing at all other than downloading the script. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nmap's [NSE](http://nmap.org/book/nse.html) scripts have (at least) two conditions which are required be true before they will run:

1. The script must be selected. In your case, you selected it with `--script redis-info`, but it could also be selected by category (e.g. `--script discovery`).
2. The script's [*rule* function](http://nmap.org/book/nse-script-format.html#nse-format-rules) must return true.

In the case of [`redis-info`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/redis-info.html), as with most scripts, the rule requires that a specific port be open. Here's the rule in its entirety:

```
portrule = shortport.port_or_service(6379, "redis-server")
```

In your case, port 6379 is [`filtered`](https://secwiki.org/w/FAQ_filtered), which means that it is **not** open, so the script will not run. This is expected, since running on a port that is not open would not be useful. You *can* force the script to run regardless of the return value of its rule, but this is rarely useful. To do so, prefix the script's name with `+`, like so: `--script +redis-info`. Note that this means it will run on **every port scanned**, so don't use it lightly!